# How to return Python PWLF Standard Error for each segment

Tags: python, piecewise

I'm reading through the documentation for PWLF for running piecewise regressions. When viewing the output for the standard error its reported as a standard error for each point in the regression line, not each segment.

For example if 2 segments are specified using fitfast(), 3 standard error values will be returned with using standard_errors(). What would be the most efficient way to return a standard error for each segment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 segments there are 3 standard error values, because there are 3 model parameters. For *N* linear segments there will *N+1* model parameters.

Each standard error value is for each model parameter, and not the model overall.

The parameters with the two linear segment model are the following:

1. the y-intercept for the piecewise linear model
2. the slope of the the first line segment
3. the difference in slope between the second line and the first line